# Convertir yaml a json desde url en node

Tags: json, nodejs, yaml

> Hola, necesito de convertir un archivo yaml a json, el yaml esta en una url. Probé utilizando  js-yaml de la siguiente manera

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs   = require('fs');

try {
  const doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('http://localhost:8080/file.yaml','utf8'));
  console.log(doc);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

**Agredeceria su ayuda**

Answer (score 1):

por el momento esta es una posible solución

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs   = require('fs');
const http = require("http");
const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.yaml");

http.get("http://localhost:8080/file.yaml", response => {
  response.pipe(file);
});

try {
  const doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync("file.yaml", 'utf8'));
  console.log(doc);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```